# Find dynamically word in NSString

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, nsstring

```
NSString * stringExample1=@"www.mysite.com/word-4-word-1-1-word-word-2-word-817061.html";

NSString * stringExample2=@"www.mysite.com/word-4-5-1-1-word-1-5-word-11706555.html";
```

I try to find  `-` and `.` Inside of `NSString`.

```
NSRange range = [string rangeOfString:@"-"];
NSUInteger start = range.location;
NSUInteger end = start + range.length;

NSRange rangeDot= [string rangeOfString:@"."];
NSUInteger startt = rangeDot.location;
NSUInteger endt = startt + rangeDot.length;
```

But it's can't be successful. It's showing first place. How can I get  `817061` and `11706555` inside of `Nstring`?

Thank you .

Comment: @Dilip In his original string ** was not there. your have formatted his code and his bold text prefixed and suffixed with **.

Comment: @βḧäṙℊặṿῗ Yeah i realized it thanx for update.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will work for you,

```
 NSArray *strArry=[stringExample1 componentsSeparatedByString:@"-"];

 NSString *result =[strArry lastObject];

 NSString *resultstring= [result  stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@".html" withString:@""];
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to find the match is by using regulars expressions with **NSRegularExpression**.

```
NSString * stringEx=@"www.mysite.com/word-4-word-1-1-word-word-2-word-817061.html";

NSError *error = NULL;
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"-(\\d*).html$"
                                                                       options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive
                                                                        error:&error];

NSArray *matches = [regex matchesInString:stringEx options:NSMatchingReportCompletion range:NSMakeRange(0, [stringEx length])];
if ([matches count] > 0)
{
    NSString* resultString = [stringEx substringWithRange:[matches[0] rangeAtIndex:1]];
    NSLog(@"Matched: %@", resultString);
}
```

Make sure you use an extra `\` escape character in the regex `NSString` whenever needed.

**UPDATE**

I did a test using the two different approaches (regex vs string splitting) with the code below:

```
NSDate *timeBefore = [NSDate date];

NSError *error = NULL;
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"-(\\d*).html$"
                                                                       options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive
                                                                        error:&error];

for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
{
    NSArray *matches = [regex matchesInString:stringEx options:NSMatchingReportCompletion range:NSMakeRange(0, [stringEx length])];
    if ([matches count] > 0)
    {
        NSString* resultString = [stringEx substringWithRange:[matches[0] rangeAtIndex:1]];
    }
}

NSTimeInterval timeSpent = [timeBefore timeIntervalSinceNow];
NSLog(@"Time: %.5f", timeSpent*-1);
```

on the simulator the differences are not significant, but running on an iPhone 4 I got the following results:

```
2013-11-25 10:24:19.795 NotifApp[406:60b] Time: 11.45771 // string splitting
2013-11-25 10:25:10.451 NotifApp[412:60b] Time: 7.55713 // regex
```

so I guess the best approach depends on case to case.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to find if it contains at least one of **-** or **.** ?

You can use -rangeOfCharacterFromSet:

```
NSCharacterSet *CharacterSet = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"-."];
NSRange range = [YourString rangeOfCharacterFromSet:CharacterSet];
if (range.location == NSNotFound) 
{
    // no - or . in the string
}
else 
{
    // - or . are present
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this simple Regular Expression.

```
    NSString * stringExample1=@"www.mysite.com/word-4-word-1-1-word-word-2-word-84354354353.html";
    NSError  *error  = NULL;

    NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression
                                  regularExpressionWithPattern:@"(\\-\\d*\\.)"
                                  options:0
                                  error:&error];

    NSRange range              = [regex rangeOfFirstMatchInString:stringExample1
                                               options:0
                                                 range:NSMakeRange(0, [stringExample1 length])];
    range                      = NSMakeRange(range.location+1, range.length-2);
    NSString *result           = [stringExample1 substringWithRange:range];
    NSLog(@"%@",result);
```